# immediate = true didn't work

Tags: immediate

I am trying to create a row which includes Delete and Add Row buttons. When delete is clicked, it should ignore the validations on the inputs. So, I used `immediate="true"` to do it. But it doesn't seem to work. What might be wrong? 
This is my code... I omitted the other lines and focused on the lines that seems not working:

```xml
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" />  
<apex:repeat id="sampleSection" value="{!someValue}" var="XY">
....
<div class="slds-button-group" role="group" style="height: 40px;">
<apex:commandButton value="Delete" id="delRowBTN" title="Delete" action="{!removerow}"  reRender="outputTable" oncomplete="return false;" immediate="true">
<apex:param name="rowForDel" value="{!cnt}" assignTo="{!rowNumber}"/>
</apex:commandButton>   
</div>
....
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: One other thing I just noticed, apex:variable in apex:repeat is unsupported. You may need to find an alternative way to write this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `immediate` skips validations, but also skips the `action` method as well. Instead, surround your button with an `apex:actionRegion`, whose purpose is to limit the submitted data to just the data within it:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!removerow}"  reRender="outputTable" oncomplete="return false;">
<apex:param name="rowForDel" value="{!cnt}" assignTo="{!rowNumber}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Note also that you have to use `apex:commandLink` for `apex:param` to work; parameters are not supported on buttons, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm). If you still want a button, you'd have to restructure your code to use a wrapper class so you can delete the appropriate record.

Comment: N.B. undocumented, but Params work on commandButton if you have `reRender=`

Comment: @cropredy Interesting. I remember trying it once and it didn't work even with reRender. Generally, I tell people if it's not documented, it shouldn't be used. It might work, it might not, which is why it's not documented.